# How to make an image looks as it is?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

How can I make the image looks at the same size as it is, for the PC, the picture looks bigger than it's shown in the mobile, which looks smaller.

Here it is

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

Comment: I guess it's a matter of screen density. Without any further details, no specific answer is possible.

Comment: put this android:scaleType="fitCenter"

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work, check http://oi57.tinypic.com/28i7zhx.jpg

Comment: FD_ Maybe you're right, but lets wait for more :)

Answer (score 0):

use below code to achieve your requirement

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

you need to use  `android:scaleType="fitXY"` property into your **image view**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to establish the drawable as background?

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/image" />
```